# Area of Triangle in n-Dimensional Euclidean Space

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, area

Given 3 points $x_1,x_2,x_3\in\mathbb{R}^n$ in Euclidean space. What is the area of the triangle they span?

Of course the formulas for $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ are well known. But how do the formulas generalize to higher dimensions?

My motivation is to generalize the formula stated in the publication *Polygon Laplacian Made Simple* by Bunge et al. Please, note that I am not looking for the volume of a "simplex". In my problem, the number of points is always 3 regardless of the dimension. Thank you!

Comment: The $2$-dimensional area is the same no matter the dimension in which it is embedded.

Comment: A triangle exists in a plane, so it doesn't matter what dimensional space it is embedded in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**
You can use [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)
Remember that the distance between two points $x,y$ in euclidean standard space is:
$$d(x,y)=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-y_i)^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

The area of a triangle in any dimension is given by
$$A = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\langle u, u\rangle \langle v, v\rangle - \langle u, v\rangle^2}$$
where  $u = x_1 - x_2, v = x_1 - x_3$  and dot product $\langle  \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ .